# How to keep geolocation running when I switch pages in the same app?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I'm developing a location tracking app using react native geolocation. Right now the geolocation tracking only works when I'm on the same page. I want it to be alive even when I navigate to other pages in the same app. I hope it could retain the state until I navigate back and stop it. Is there any way I can do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a listener and kill it when you want: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstater

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncStorage to keep your geolocation data throughout every pages of your application.